# Suma de vocales ciclo for

Tags: c, bucle-for, inicializacion

Hola cómo están necesito si me pueden ayudar tengo que hacer un programa en c con ciclo for les pasó el código consiste en poner una frase y en teoría debería sumar las vocales de dicha frase pero mi problema es que se ejecuta todo pero no me suma las vocalese tira todos los valores en 0 me podrán dar una mano para ver qué me falta o en qué le estoy errando? Gracias

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <iostream>
     #include <string.h>


     int main()
     {
        char frase [50],vocales[5];
        printf("Escriba una frase:\n");
        scanf("frase");

        for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
        {
        vocales[i]=0;
        }
        for(int b=0;b<50;b++)
        {
        switch(frase[b])
        {
        case 'a': vocales [0]++; break;
        case 'e': vocales [1]++; break;
        case 'i': vocales [2]++; break;
         case 'o': vocales [3]++; break;
        case 'u': vocales [4]++; break;
        }
        }
        printf("las vocales presentes 
       son:\n");
        printf("a: %d\n", vocales[0]);
        printf("e: %d\n", vocales[1]);
        printf("i: %d\n", vocales[2]);
        printf("o: %d\n", vocales[3]);
        printf("u: %d\n", vocales[4]);

    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Eso no compila con el salto de línea en el printf del resultado... seguro ese es el código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que realmente no estás guardando lo que le pides al usuario en ninguna parte, así que estás iterando sobre un array vacío de 50 posiciones. Si usas `scanf` para guardar eso en la variable, te va a funcionar.

Lo otro es que toca decirle a scanf qué recibir usando una expresion regular que incluya el espacio. Por defecto ese man no recibe el string sino hasta el espacio, así que está contando bien pero el input estaba truncado. Añadiendo un printf se ve eso... la otra es usar fgets (que de hecho, entiendo que es más seguro) con algo como `fgets(frase, MAX_SIZE, stdin);`...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>


 int main()
 {
    const int LONGITUD_ARR = 50;
    char frase[LONGITUD_ARR];
    int vocales[5];
    printf("Escriba una frase:\n");
    scanf("%49[0-9a-zA-Z ]", frase);
    printf("Escribiste %s.\n", frase);
    
    for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
    {
        vocales[i]=0;
    }
    
    for(int b=0; b < LONGITUD_ARR; b++)
    {
        switch(frase[b])
        {
            case 'a': vocales[0]++; break;
            case 'e': vocales[1]++; break;
            case 'i': vocales[2]++; break;
            case 'o': vocales[3]++; break;
            case 'u': vocales[4]++; break;
        }
    }
    printf("las vocales presentes son:\n");
    printf("a: %d\n", vocales[0]);
    printf("e: %d\n", vocales[1]);
    printf("i: %d\n", vocales[2]);
    printf("o: %d\n", vocales[3]);
    printf("u: %d\n", vocales[4]);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayudar...Ahora me arroja un valor pero no las suma  por ejemplo le pongo "hola mundo " y me sale a:1 e:0 i:0 o:1 u:0 me toma los valores de la primer frase osea Hola los valores de mundo los salta

Comment: @ElArgento Eh, no tuvimos en cuenta los espacios, je. Voy... editado

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda te lo agradezco!!

Comment: @ElArgento Con gusto! Recuerda marcarla como aceptada si te resolvió la duda